# {} vs. ${} in and ` vs. ' (backtick vs quote)

Tags: javascript, jsx

I am new to JSX, and javascript in general, and I am confused by `{}` having multiple meanings based on what is in and around them. I am confused about the difference between `{}` and `${}` in the following example from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-classes).
In an example explaining hooks, we see `<button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>`

Here, the innermost curly braces indicate that a JS object with one `key: value` pair is what is being passed as the sole parameter to this.setState().

Later, in the `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` methods we see `` document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times/`; ``

In this snippet, the curly braces do not surround a `key: value` pair so I know it not a JSON object. It's inside {} in JSX so this.state.count should just evaluate to a number but what is the meaning of the `$` in this expression?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `` and $ combination is a way to concatenate strings that's easier to read than the old way of using `+`.

For example say you have obtained the users firstname through some input you might output some string like 
`Hi There Mark!` 
where Mark is the users name. 
You can do this with either 
`"Hi There" + user.firstname + "!"`
or
`` `Hi There ${user.firstname}!` ``.

Answer (score 1):

In **JavaScript** content between backticks is a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and `${...}` is the syntax you can use to embed a JavaScript expression inside the template.

In **JSX** `{...}` is used to assign a dynamic value (as opposed to a static one) to a prop on a component.